# How to restrict minimized value to be above a specific value?

Tags: python, scipy, minimization

Let's say I have this piece of code:

```
def test(params, *args):
    return params[0] + params[1]
minVal = minimize(test, [0.01, 0.02]) # I want minVal to be lowest non-negative value
```

With such a constraint, I could restrict the result to be above 0:

```
# forces test(params) >= 0
con = [{"type" : "ineq", "fun" : test}]
minVal = minimize(test, x0=[0.01, 0.02], constraints=con)
```

But what if I want the value to be above 4? Is it possible to specify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Just define your `test` function as:

```
def test(params, *args):
    return params[0] + params[1] - 4
```

Alternatively, if you do not want to change the `test` function, define:

```
con = [{"type" : "ineq", "fun" : lambda x: test(x)-4}]
minVal = minimize(test, x0=[0.01, 0.02], constraints=con)
```